# boost:bind and io_service in two different classes

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio, boost-bind

I am kind'a new to Boost.

I would like to know how to construct an io_service in one class and send it tasks from another class.

My problem is `BOOST_ASIO_COMPLETION_HANDLER_CHECK` complains and wont let the code compile.

He is a skeleton of my code:

type_defs.h (this has the function to be wrapped and sent to the io_service)

```
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"

namespace fs = ::boost::filesystem;

typedef boost::function<void(const fs::path path)> parse_and_aggregate_fun_t;
```

io_service_processors.h (this is the class that will construct the io_service and wait for job posts).

```
namespace asio = boost::asio;

typedef std::unique_ptr<asio::io_service::work> work_ptr;

class io_service_processors {
public:
    io_service_processors(int tc);
    virtual ~io_service_processors();

    void init();
    void post_job(parse_and_aggregate_fun_t file_job);

private:
    int thread_count;
    asio::io_service* service;
    boost::mutex mtx;
    work_ptr * work;
    boost::thread_group workers;
};
```

io_service_processors.cpp

```
namespace asio = boost::asio;   

io_service_processors::io_service_processors(int tc):thread_count(tc) {

}

io_service_processors::~io_service_processors() {
       // clean up code here removed.
}

void io_service_processors::init() {
    this->service = new asio::io_service();
    this->work = new work_ptr(new asio::io_service::work(*(this->service)));
    for(int i = 0; i < this->thread_count; ++i)
        this->workers.create_thread(boost::bind(&asio::io_service::run, this->service));
}

void io_service_processors::post_job(parse_and_aggregate_fun_t file_job) {
    this->service->post(file_job);
}
```

job_discoverer.cpp (this one will discover files and send their paths to to the io_service, the function `parse_and_aggregate` will the actual work for opening the file and processing it, `process` will simply post the wrapped function to the io_service, `this->processor` is simply a pointer to the io_service wrapper class above).

```
void job_discoverer::process(const fs::path path){
    std::cout << "Posting file: " << path.string() << std::endl;
    if(this->processor)
        this->processor->post_job(
                boost::bind(&job_discoverer::parse_and_aggregate, this, path)
                );
}

void job_discoverer::parse_and_aggregate(const fs::path path) {
    std::cout << "Parsing and aggregating file: " << path.string() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this->service->post(file_job);
```

tries to post a job, but it's not a nullary function. Of course this can't work. Did you mean to bind a value to the `path` parameter?

Even more interesting, that function (`io_service_processors::post_job`) is never used. If we - for humor sake - assume that `post_job` was actually meant where `post_file_job` was written, then you'll find that you actually pass a nullary bind-expression. So, fix it:

```
typedef boost::function<void()> any_job;
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b97d65fa306ea6b)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

namespace fs = ::boost::filesystem;

typedef boost::function<void()> any_job;

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
namespace asio = boost::asio;

typedef std::unique_ptr<asio::io_service::work> work_ptr;

class io_service_processors {
public:
    io_service_processors(int tc);
    virtual ~io_service_processors();

    void init();
    void post_job(any_job file_job);

private:
    int thread_count;
    asio::io_service* service;
    boost::mutex mtx;
    work_ptr * work;
    boost::thread_group workers;
};

io_service_processors::io_service_processors(int tc):thread_count(tc) {

}

io_service_processors::~io_service_processors() {
       // clean up code here removed.
}

void io_service_processors::init() {
    this->service = new asio::io_service();
    this->work = new work_ptr(new asio::io_service::work(*(this->service)));
    for(int i = 0; i < this->thread_count; ++i)
        this->workers.create_thread(boost::bind(&asio::io_service::run, this->service));
}

void io_service_processors::post_job(any_job file_job) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    this->service->post(file_job);
}

struct job_discoverer {

    boost::optional<io_service_processors> processor;

    void process(const fs::path path){
        std::cout << "Posting file: " << path.string() << std::endl;
        if(this->processor)
            this->processor->post_job(
                    boost::bind(&job_discoverer::parse_and_aggregate, this, path)
                    );
    }

    void parse_and_aggregate(const fs::path path) {
        std::cout << "Parsing and aggregating file: " << path.string() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
}
```

Comment: My apologies about the confusion related to post_job vs post_file_job. But your assumption it right, post_file_job is just a typo. And I meant to call post_job.

Comment: Thank you sehe for the efforts. I really appreciate it. I do not usually post code that can be compiled because I do not want people do my work for me. I want to do it on my own. I just ask people to review the code (the most important parts of it) and guide me to the right way. I want to do my own work.

Comment: "because I do not want people do my work for me"  is a strange motive. Making it correct and complete **prevents** people wasting time on non-existing or impossible problems. **Not** doing it is bordering on the impolite.

Answer (score 1):

In `io_service_processors::post_job` you put `parse_and_aggregate_fun_t` to `io_service::post`. The function signature for `handler` in `io_service::post` [must be void()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/post.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service.post.parameters). Yours is `void(const fs::path)`

Comment: That's only half the story though

Comment: @sehe Sure, but it's enough of the story, the rest is simply assumptions as he didn't post an MVCE. You followed the rest for "humor sake", but I apparently didn't have enough humor left ^^ His call to `io_service::post` is a clear error, the rest is just background noise that may or may not exist once he fixed all follow up mistakes

Comment: On the contrary. His call to post only seems to be in error because he got the type for `parse_and_aggregate_fun_t` wrong. The call is arguably correct. And yes, I noted to the OP that he should have made a more careful SSCCE

Comment: @sehe I don't even know why we argue about this. I made little effort, you made more effort. Is there any more to say about this ? ^^

Comment: Not really. I wasn't even aware we were arguing o.O

Comment: @sehe Well I rather meant "talk" instead of "argue" :D "Argue" is also used for normal talking in my native language, my bad. Anyway this is getting off-topic, so im out.

Comment: @sehe and Slyps thank you both for you efforts. I really appreciate it. I tried to read the documentation as much as possible. But apparently I missed that part. I will try it and see if it works.